# How can I allow a user to only enter certain characters and also make displaying pound signs simpler?

Tags: c++, loops, variables, audio, char

second post on here. Please keep in mind that I'm a noob to C++ so give me the benefit of the doubt and try to keep your answers simple :)

Ok, so I have this block of code here:

```
string answer14;
cout << "So, A, B, C or D?";
cin >> answer14;

cout << "Ok, your final answer is " << answer14 << "." << endl;
PlaySound(TEXT("C:/Users/user/Downloads/Millionaire/£8000final.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
Sleep (4000);

if (answer14 == "B" || answer14 == "b")
    {
        cout << "You've just won HALF A MILLION POUNDS!" << endl;
        PlaySound(TEXT("C:/Users/user/Downloads/Millionaire/£500000win.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
        Sleep(6000);
    }
else
    {
        cout << "You've just LOST " << char(156) << "218,000! I cannot believe it! That's horrible!" << endl;
        PlaySound(TEXT("C:/Users/user/Downloads/Millionaire/£16000lose.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
        Sleep (4000);
        PlaySound(TEXT("C:/Users/user/Downloads/Millionaire/gameOver.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
        cout << "Thanks for playing! Press any key to exit the game" << endl;
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

So what this code does is allows the user to enter an answer then play some sound files and then go to the if and else statments to check if their answer is correct. I've made an or operator in the if statement to allow them to enter both cases of letter. However, I would like to make a block of code that restricts the user to only enter A, B, C or D (hopefully it includes the function to detect accidental spaces in an answer as well) in upper and/or lowercase and, if they were to enter an incorrect option, alert them then allow them to reenter an answer (putting this in a loop would be great too, so they can enter an incorrect answer any amount of times without it going to the else statement and treating their answer as wrong) . Any ideas on how to do this?

Also, you'll notice I'm using char(156) to display a pound sign. Any simpler and less tedious ways to do this?

Remember, I'm new to C++ (and programming in general) so please keep that in mind and try to make your answer as simple as possible. Thanks very much :)

Comment: So why not try writing a loop, comparing each character in the string?

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.

Comment: Ok Dan, apologies and thanks Paul, I'll give that a shot.

Comment: Paul, could you give me an example of what code I could write (Again, sorry, I'm new) ?